# PHP exec() command doesn't execute in Apache Windows

Tags: php, apache, exec, execute

I'm trying to run the PHP exec() command, but it doesn't execute. It works on NGINX but doesn't work on Apache. I'm using Windows.

```
$cmdex = exec('cmd /c C:\nginx-1.20.2\html\pythonbatch.bat');
echo $cmdex;
```

I've tried different solutions like changing the permission and config files, but it doesn't work. When I run the PHP program, it outputs this but doesn't execute:

```
C:\Apache24\htdocs>exit
```

PHP works fine in general, but when I do anything that has to do with executing, it doesn't work.

EDIT: To clarify, PHP works when executing the command standalone but doesn't work in browser.